# concatenate survival matrix for MARK

Tags: r

I'm attempting to arrange survival data for use in MARK so i want to concatenate every column into a new column with no separation between the values.

Sample of data in a data frame:

```
  Tag      31/08/2010 18/09/2012 3/09/2013    
 9851          1          0         0    
 3875          1          0         1      
 0922          0          1         0        
 9192          0          1         0
```

This works and is what i want

```
 str_c(mydata[1,1],mydata[1,2],mydata[1,3])   
 [1] "100"
```

But i have many more sample dates than this and other sites where the dates and/or number of samples differ so i thought something like this to avoid having to change the code above for each site but this doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve this without changing mydata[1,1],mydata[1,2],mydata[1,3] everytime i change site or data set?

```
 str_c(mydata[1,1:length(Date.list)])
```

Sample data if it helps

```
 mydata <- c(1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0)
 m <- matrix(mydata, nrow=4,ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
```

Thanks for any help with this small but annoying issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `apply`

```
apply(m,1,function(x) paste0(x,collapse = ''))
[1] "100" "101" "010" "010"
```